# Does Xcode support shader debugger in iPhone when debugging metal shader?

Tags: metal

My macOS version: macOS Mojave, Version 10.14.4
My iPhone device: iPhone X, iOS 11.2.2
My Xcode version: Xcode 10.2.1

In my scheme -> Options:
1. GPU Frame Capture: Automatically Enabled
2. Metal API Validation: Enabled

When I want to use capture GPU frame to debug metal shader, the shader debugger icon was gray, suggesting that Shader Debugger is not supported, update your operating system in order to support the shader debugger.

I want to know whether Xcode supports shader debugger on iPhone. If do suppport, then how to use it.

Thank you!

Comment: It should be supported, but it's extremely buggy, not working or giving wrong results many times. 
You may have better luck if you upgrade to iOS 12, but no guarantees...

Comment: @Itai Ok, I will try it later.